# Taxonomist badges awarded to users with less than 1500 reputation

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

According to the [privileges chart](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), one can [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) for new questions once they reach 1500 reputation. Otherwise, they will get an error message "Creating the new tag '`...`' requires at least 1500 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead."

[image]

However, if you go to the [list of users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11?page=2) that have been awarded the "Taxonomist" badge, there are a few users who recently obtained this badge before they reached the 1500 threshold, even though "Taxonomist" should only be possible for uses who have reached at least 1500 reputation.

How come there are a few users with less than 1500 reputation recently obtain the Taxonomist badge?

Comment: Is it okay if I can mention one user who obtained the Taxonomist badge before 1500 reputation?

Comment: I read that as 'taxidermist'

Comment: "Is it okay if I can mention one user who obtained the Taxonomist badge before 1500 reputation?" -- Yes, it would be okay. That is a neutral-to-positive fact about the user, and one highly unlikely to attract undue attention.

Comment: The tag was created when nobody had any rep yet, Sep 2008 was the month that SO got started.  'Took a long time to acquire 50 questions.

Comment: For half a second I didn't think that said "newtag"

Comment: While not the overarching answer, I think there also may be isolated cases of people reaching the threshold and then losing reputation.  From my own feed, I've seen reduction in reputation for downvotes and for removed users (https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed).  If I recall, when I was at the threshold, I temporarily lost a privilege, but not the badge. Putting this in comments instead of answer because I can't verify, and it's not a complete answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The threshold for tag creation used to be lower: from zero on the first days of the site, it got raised to 100, then to 250, [and finally to 1500](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51949/242059).

Comment: What about the one from April 20th to a user with 266 rep?

Comment: @TinyGiant and Hans: The tag [was created in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120470/2751851); the badge was awarded once it reached 50 questions. (This example does indicate the threshold used to be even lower in the distant past, or even nonexistent.)

Comment: @duplode Actually, the user created it [back in 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/120470/revisions) (it's on the original revision).

Comment: @animuson Indeed -- it seems I have looked at the wrong tab for quoting the date.